# Alternative for Multipeer-connectivity tvOS swift

Tags: swift, swift2, tvos, multipeer-connectivity, apple-tv

I have been looking around trying to figure out how crossy road developers and beat sports developers have made their remote controller "add-on." First I thought Multipeer-connectivity, but after trying to test it on the Apple TV realized the framework was not support, why? Makes no sense to me, but anyways. So my question is, does anyone know what cross road developers did?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Hipster Whale (Crossy Road developers) used [Unity](https://unity3d.com) to make that, so you might want to look into that.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to create a software-based game controller, you don't really need peer-to-peer.  I've used NSNetService and made my framework available as open source: https://github.com/robreuss/VirtualGameController

Core Bluetooth would also work but will not give you the same performance as WiFi (NSNetService).